# export all string between spaces

Tags: php

how to export all strings in `'Hi my Name is Mahdi'` to array like with this: `$arr=array('Hi','my','Name','is','Mahdi');` with use UTF8

Comment: [`explode($delimiter, $string)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$string = "Hi my name is mahdi";

$arr = explode(" ",$string);

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various answers to similar questions here, but you want `$arr = explode(' ', $string);`

If you check the [**explode()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) documentation you'll see that it takes to arguments; the delimiter by which to split the string by (in this case, a space: `' '`), and the string you want to split.

You could split other strings like `hello,my,name,is,Maccath` by commas by using `explode(',', 'hello,my,name,is,Maccath')`